# Basis & Linear Maps

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ is a basis of $V$ and $W$ is finite dimensional. Prove that if $T$ is an element of $L(V, W)$, then there exists a basis of $W$ such that all the entries in the first column of $M(T)$ are nonnegative real numbers.

Comment: What approach did you try before posting the Question?  What difficulty do you encounter?  A brief Question like this may solicit Answers that are also too brief to be helpful, or that spend too much effort on material that you already know.

Comment: I actually didn't know how to approach this question (since I'm quite unfamiliar with linear transformation/matrix of linear maps), so the answers given were enough to help me start thinking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first column of the matrix is $T(v_1)$.  Suppose
$$
T(v_1)=a_1w_1+a_2w_2+\cdots +a_kw_k
$$
where $w_1,\ldots,w_k$ is some basis for $W$.  Then the first column is just $(a_1,\ldots,a_k)^T$.  If any of the $a_i$ are negative, change $w_i$ out for $-w_i$.

Comment: What do you mean the first column is just (a1,…,ak)T?

Comment: @Carmen the entries in the first column of the matrix are $a_1,\ldots,a_k$.

Comment: @Carmen It's because the matrix $A$ associated with your matrix $T$ looks like: $A = \left[ [T(v_1)]_W\ [T(v_2)]_W\ \cdots\ [T(v_n)]_W\right]$, where the $i$th column is the coordinates of $T(v_i)$ written out in the basis $\{w_1, \dots, w_k\} \in W$.